# Not in index Error

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, numpy

xtrain is a numpy array

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

outer_kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=27, shuffle=True)
final_scores = list()
for train, test in outer_kfold.split(xtrain):
    x_train, x_test = xtrain[train], xtrain[test]
    y_train, y_test = ytrain[train], ytest[test]
    
    model=LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    
    preds = model.predict(x_test)
    
    final_scores.append(accuracy_score(y_test, preds))
    print("Score:", final_scores[-1])
    print("\nAverage Score:", np.average(final_scores))
        
    model=LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
        
    preds = model.predict(x_test)
        
    final_scores.append(accuracy_score(y_test, preds))
    print("Score:", final_scores[-1])
    print("\nAverage Score:", np.average(final_scores))




 Error
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    /var/folders/vd/lb0gkn7j2t34s4ljbgdb7g5r0000gn/T/ipykernel_1376/2946208749.py in <module>
          5 for train, test in outer_kfold.split(xtrain):
          6     x_train, x_test = xtrain[train], xtrain[test]
    ----> 7     y_train, y_test = ytrain[train], ytest[test]
          8 
          9     model=LogisticRegression()
    
    /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
        964             return self._get_values(key)
        965 
    --> 966         return self._get_with(key)
        967 
        968     def _get_with(self, key):
    
    /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_with(self, key)
        999             #  (i.e. self.iloc) or label-based (i.e. self.loc)
       1000             if not self.index._should_fallback_to_positional():
    -> 1001                 return self.loc[key]
       1002             else:
       1003                 return self.iloc[key]
    
    /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
        929 
        930             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    --> 931             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
        932 
        933     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: tuple):
    
    /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
       1151                     raise ValueError("Cannot index with multidimensional key")
       1152 
    -> 1153                 return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
       1154 
       1155             # nested tuple slicing
    
    /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_iterable(self, key, axis)
       1091 
       1092         # A collection of keys
    -> 1093         keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis)
       1094         return self.obj._reindex_with_indexers(
       1095             {axis: [keyarr, indexer]}, copy=True, allow_dups=True
    
    /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
       1312             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
       1313 
    -> 1314         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
       1315 
       1316         if needs_i8_conversion(ax.dtype) or isinstance(
    
    /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
       1375 
       1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
    -> 1377             raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
       1378 
       1379 
    
    KeyError: '[7, 39, 44, 45, 54, 58, 74, 79, 82, 90, 94, 98, 99, 103, 108, 115, 116, 119, 130, 134, 147, 157, 159, 161, 177, 186, 188, 192, 201, 203, 217, 218, 219, 220, 229, 231, 234, 239, 248, 250, 254, 273, 276, 285, 288, 291, 299, 301, 305, 307, 308, 313, 314, 321, 324, 325, 331, 342, 343, 345, 347, 354, 368, 372, 386, 394, 407, 413, 433, 438, 442, 447, 448, 462, 470, 481, 487, 496, 503, 507, 513, 517, 536, 538, 545, 554, 558, 559, 569, 573, 574, 587, 589, 592, 596, 599, 602, 605, 607, 608, 623, 627, 634, 642, 644, 650, 654, 662, 664, 666, 675, 687, 691, 705, 712, 714, 716, 717, 718, 724, 729, 755, 758, 761, 781, 783, 793, 802, 813, 822, 823, 847, 858, 859, 863, 867, 871, 874, 895, 900, 911, 925, 941, 946, 951, 955, 958, 961, 963, 968, 975, 982, 995, 1002, 1005, 1028, 1038, 1041, 1049, 1050, 1051, 1060, 1063, 1070, 1071, 1073, 1075, 1089, 1117, 1122, 1139, 1144, 1145, 1153, 1155, 1156, 1159, 1160, 1162, 1167, 1169, 1172, 1177, 1178, 1183, 1190, 1197, 1198, 1213, 1217, 1221, 1224, 1225, 1227, 1233, 1253, 1256, 1262, 1264, 1266, 1271, 1282, 1287, 1288, 1289, 1297, 1299, 1305, 1307, 1308, 1322, 1328, 1331, 1332, 1342, 1347, 1356, 1373, 1380, 1392, 1406, 1409, 1416, 1422, 1447, 1454, 1458, 1463, 1494, 1508, 1513, 1519, 1520, 1525, 1532, 1534, 1536, 1540, 1544, 1550, 1554, 1564, 1578, 1604, 1614, 1620, 1624, 1628, 1652, 1657, 1664, 1676, 1682, 1683, 1685, 1686, 1692, 1703, 1711, 1717, 1720, 1729, 1732, 1735, 1736, 1740, 1743, 1745, 1748, 1750, 1753, 1758, 1768, 1773, 1785, 1790, 1793, 1814, 1817, 1827, 1828, 1829, 1851, 1857, 1873, 1885, 1892, 1909, 1917, 1924, 1929, 1933, 1939, 1945, 1947, 1956, 1958, 1961, 1971, 1988, 1989, 1990, 2017, 2019, 2025, 2031, 2040, 2045, 2054, 2064, 2065, 2089, 2090, 2097, 2098, 2119, 2120, 2134, 2136, 2140, 2157, 2161, 2164, 2168, 2174, 2181, 2196, 2209, 2229, 2252, 2255, 2262, 2271, 2285, 2296, 2325, 2328, 2331, 2333, 2345, 2349, 2351, 2353, 2355, 2362, 2363, 2364, 2377, 2378, 2385, 2398, 2402, 2403, 2407, 2408, 2411, 2437, 2438, 2445, 2450, 2456, 2458, 2481, 2487, 2488, 2489, 2491, 2495, 2505, 2512, 2514, 2532, 2537, 2539, 2550, 2567, 2570, 2573, 2586, 2588, 2593, 2597, 2605, 2606, 2608, 2615, 2619, 2624, 2637, 2639, 2640, 2645, 2652, 2653, 2656, 2657, 2666, 2677, 2684, 2688, 2694, 2696, 2698, 2701, 2702, 2704, 2706, 2711, 2722, 2723, 2735, 2736, 2755, 2773, 2774, 2776, 2787, 2800, 2807, 2812, 2815, 2820, 2827, 2831, 2837, 2842, 2856, 2858, 2861, 2864, 2866, 2868, 2878, 2883, 2887, 2889, 2897, 2899, 2900, 2901, 2909, 2917, 2918, 2919, 2921, 2927, 2929, 2932, 2939, 2954, 2959, 2981, 2989, 2999, 3001, 3005, 3014, 3016, 3023, 3032, 3039, 3053, 3069, 3072, 3079, 3080, 3081, 3092, 3095, 3099, 3100, 3108, 3111, 3112, 3126, 3134, 3140, 3144, 3153, 3157, 3165, 3167, 3191, 3196, 3198, 3207, 3210, 3211, 3224, 3234, 3242, 3248, 3265, 3272, 3283, 3285, 3287, 3291, 3293, 3304, 3329, 3338, 3339, 3369, 3370, 3371, 3376, 3382, 3384, 3391, 3397, 3419, 3422, 3423, 3426, 3427, 3431, 3435, 3455, 3458, 3461, 3463, 3472, 3473, 3477, 3484, 3485, 3489, 3491, 3492, 3498, 3500, 3502, 3504, 3505, 3511, 3516, 3522, 3531, 3532, 3554, 3563, 3565, 3571, 3585, 3588, 3593, 3595, 3611, 3619, 3628, 3636, 3644, 3645, 3658, 3662, 3663, 3665, 3669, 3675, 3680, 3689, 3690, 3692, 3696, 3715, 3716, 3729, 3737, 3738, 3741, 3755, 3761, 3762, 3767, 3769, 3771, 3777, 3784, 3789, 3792, 3801, 3802, 3803, 3807, 3808, 3811, 3812, 3816, 3819, 3823, 3829, 3830, 3832, 3834, 3835, 3849, 3862, 3865, 3866, 3872, 3878, 3891, 3897, 3901, 3903, 3906, 3916, 3920, 3925, 3928, 3935, 3938, 3943, 3945, 3954, 3963, 3979, 3985, 3986, 3988, 3993, 4008, 4023, 4029, 4040, 4045, 4051, 4058, 4060, 4067, 4071, 4076, 4078, 4084, 4086, 4089, 4098, 4106, 4109, 4113, 4117, 4124, 4133, 4140, 4145, 4152, 4154, 4158, 4165, 4175, 4184, 4192, 4194, 4195, 4203, 4205, 4207, 4224, 4227, 4228, 4230, 4232, 4236, 4253, 4258, 4261, 4268, 4269, 4272, 4276, 4288, 4290, 4295, 4296, 4301, 4305, 4306, 4322, 4326, 4331, 4332, 4364, 4367, 4369, 4370, 4381, 4382, 4396, 4399, 4406, 4410, 4422, 4423, 4424, 4425, 4429, 4437, 4444, 4445, 4446, 4460, 4462, 4464, 4479, 4481, 4482, 4484, 4486, 4487, 4492, 4495, 4497, 4503, 4510, 4514, 4520, 4530, 4544, 4546, 4556, 4557, 4558, 4563, 4569, 4571, 4575, 4576, 4583, 4586, 4589, 4591, 4594, 4599, 4613, 4621, 4627, 4629, 4636, 4646, 4649, 4652, 4656, 4661, 4673, 4678, 4679, 4685, 4688, 4695, 4698, 4705, 4706, 4708, 4714, 4727, 4728, 4732, 4736, 4737, 4741, 4744, 4748, 4757, 4760, 4797, 4844, 4846, 4848, 4859, 4870, 4874, 4888, 4897, 4907, 4914, 4925, 4926, 4928, 4932, 4939, 4951, 4953, 4954, 4958, 4964, 4966, 4976, 4977, 4980, 4983, 4984, 4992, 5005, 5013, 5014, 5021, 5041, 5042, 5051, 5053, 5063, 5065, 5066, 5069, 5073, 5078, 5080, 5083, 5084, 5089, 5090, 5112, 5114, 5116, 5118, 5137, 5142, 5160, 5163, 5173, 5180, 5189, 5196, 5198, 5206, 5207, 5210, 5211, 5216, 5221, 5224, 5232, 5234, 5240, 5241, 5243, 5244, 5247, 5260, 5261, 5265, 5281, 5282, 5289, 5290, 5301, 5309, 5311, 5316, 5319, 5323, 5328, 5329, 5345, 5347, 5355, 5364, 5365, 5368, 5375, 5376, 5388, 5389, 5402, 5407, 5408, 5414, 5418, 5430, 5433, 5438, 5443, 5451, 5455, 5460, 5461, 5476, 5477, 5478, 5483, 5487, 5488, 5492, 5493, 5495, 5509, 5513, 5522, 5531, 5535, 5549, 5552, 5555, 5557, 5558, 5564, 5570, 5583, 5590, 5592, 5599, 5603, 5604, 5615, 5629, 5638, 5640, 5641, 5644, 5648, 5651, 5668, 5669, 5676, 5680, 5682, 5684, 5689, 5699, 5727, 5729, 5735, 5736, 5738, 5748, 5756, 5757, 5761, 5764, 5765, 5774, 5792, 5793, 5796, 5799, 5803, 5817, 5822, 5824, 5832, 5833, 5838, 5872, 5877, 5878, 5887, 5888, 5899, 5910, 5915, 5916, 5921, 5944, 5946, 5950, 5959, 5987, 5989, 5991, 5992, 5993, 5996, 6005, 6012, 6013, 6021, 6027, 6034, 6037, 6042, 6046, 6049, 6054, 6055, 6058, 6061, 6063, 6064, 6070, 6075, 6077, 6083, 6087, 6091, 6102, 6117, 6126, 6129, 6137, 6147, 6149, 6160, 6168, 6170, 6181, 6184, 6189, 6190, 6191, 6192, 6200, 6211, 6213, 6215, 6219, 6228, 6233, 6238, 6240, 6252, 6257, 6260, 6262, 6274, 6275, 6279, 6280, 6302, 6303, 6305, 6315, 6335, 6364, 6366, 6368, 6377, 6384, 6385, 6386, 6392, 6397, 6404, 6418, 6426, 6442, 6446, 6450, 6453] not in index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $7^{th}$ row with:

```
y_train, y_test = ytrain[train], ytrain[test]
```